# getting rid of " " from slicing in python

Tags: python, string, int, hex

I am converting two hex strings written in the format hex,hex# to a interger using the following program.

Program:

```
a=raw_input("Serial Command: ")
    if a=="q":
        break
    ser.write(a)
    time.sleep(1)
    b=ser.readline()
    print "b=",b
    azt=b[:8]
    alt=b[9:17]
    print "azt=",azt,"|","alt=",alt
    print int(azt)," ",int(alt)
```

output and trace:

```
Serial Command: z
b= 07A49B00,0006EF00#
azt= 07A49B00 | alt= 0006EF00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\celestronserial.py", line 58, in <module>
    print int(azt)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '07A49B00'
```

The int(azt/alt) function returns an error saying it is not base 10.  The culprit as you can see form the output of the "alt/azt=" lines is some white space.  Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this white space form split?  How do I get rid of it?  I tried replace(" ","") to no avail.

Comment: I presume the quoted code comes from inside a loop, since outside a loop `break` is a syntax error.

Comment: What on earth makes you think *The culprit... is some white space."*? You are trying to convert a string representing a (presumably) base-16 number, but as a string representing a base-10 number, which won't work. Read [the docs on `int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That space is only inserted by `print`.

```
In [1]: print "hello","world"
hello world
```

Your variables aren't being edited. To see what is really in your variables, don't use a comma in `print`.

```
In [2]: print "hello" + "world"
helloworld
```

As for your integer conversion, be sure to list the base:

```
int(azt, base=16)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm feeling stupid, I actually ran into this two nights ago at 1 in the morning and figured it out.  Don't know why I didn't catch it this time.  I guess it goes to show you, you're not always sharpest in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

The spaces you think you need to eliminate are coming from the print statement and are not a part of your data.  What you actually need is `int(azt, 16)`.  You need to provide a base if the base is not 10.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption about whitespace is probably incorrect, as the `print` statement automatically introduces a space between the arguments it prints.

To get the strings you want, use

```
s = "07A49B00,0006EF00#"
azt, alt = b[:-1].split(",")
```

The `[:-1]` omits the trailing `#` and then `.split()` call returns a list of the strings around commas. There should be only two, so I use an unpacking assigment to put the values into individual variables.

The real issue is your `int()` calls, which should presumably specify a base of 16 to achieve the necessary hexadecimal conversion (so, for example, `int(azt, 16)`).